# Condition to show $\{ U \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}|\mathscr{A}(UU^{\top}) = b \}$ is (is not) a manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-equations, smooth-manifolds, semidefinite-programming

Consider $\mathscr{A}: S^{n\times n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m}$, $b \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$, I would like to know when $\mathscr{M}:=\{ U \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}|\mathscr{A}(UU^{\top}) = b \}$ is a manifold. Or find a way to show it is not a manifold. For simplicity, consider the case $p<n$

In [Deterministic guarantees for Burer–Monteiro factorizations of smooth semidefinite programs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.02008.pdf), the following is stated:

> Assumption 1.1. For a given $p$ such that $\mathscr{M}$ is non-empty, constraints on (SDP) defined by $A_1, \ldots, A_m \in \mathbb{S}^{n \times n}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$ satisfy at least one of the following:
> a. $\left\{A_1 Y, \ldots, A_m Y\right\}$ are linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ for all $Y \in \mathscr{M}$; or
> b. $\left\{A_1 Y, \ldots, A_m Y\right\}$ span a subspace of constant dimension in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ for all $Y$ in an open neighborhood of $\mathscr{M}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$.
> In either case, let $m^{\prime}$ denote the dimension of the space spanned by $\left\{A_1 Y, \ldots, A_m Y\right\}$. ... Under Assumption 1.1, $\mathscr{M}$ is an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ of dimension $n p-m^{\prime}$.

Assumption a can be easily proved by noting that $\phi(Y):= \mathscr{A}(YY^{\top}) - b$ is a smooth locally (in fact global) defining function, and that $D\phi(Y)$ has full rank $m$. (For $\phi_{i}(Y) = \langle A_{i},YY^{\top} \rangle$ - $b$, $D\phi_{_{i}}(Y) = 2A_{i}Y$)

With $a$ and $b$ stated above, I have no reason to believe that if they are not satisfied, then $\mathscr{M}$ is not a smooth manifold, $\mathscr{M}$ locally may still be the zero set of some other smooth function who has full rank derivative. However, I cannot immediately find a counterexample.

> So given $\mathscr{A}, b$, how would we determine that if $\mathscr{M}$ is not a smooth manifold? And are these conditions sufficient, or if not are there stronger conditions?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or answers.